# Three.js error Uncaught TypeError following a guide

Tags: html, three.js

I have been following this guide to get three.js to work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TeMXIWRrqE

I pasted his source code from the bottom of this website: https://redstapler.co/add-3d-model-to-website-threejs/

Downloaded the model and extracted it to the directory html

Got the gtflloader and orbitcotrols from the links in the discription. I have created files with those names in the html directory and pasted the code in.

And I got the three.min.js from the official three.js download folder and I have put it the html directory.

I am getting this error. Is it me doing something wrong? Or the code is broken? If so what would be the fix?

[image]

Comment: Some more up to date tutorials [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're following an outdated tutorial, but the explanation on how to fix it is right there in yellow letters. [OrbitControls now requires a second parameter](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) with the HTML element that you want to listen to mouse events. For example, you could use the canvas that the Renderer generates:

```
THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: had to move this up to the front as well:  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });